# Morphological realisation for the Spanish language

Tags: java, nlp, morphological-analysis

Does anyone know a Morphological realisation Tool (preferably a Java one).
I am working on a project and I need to realise the correct verb "to be" providing if it is for male/female - singular/plural - first person/third person and regarding such inputs generate the correct verb "to be".
SimpleNLG is the ideal software that contains a Morphological realisation but it is only for English and French.For example : if the features are male first person singular the result will be "I", if the features are plural third person males the result will be "they".

Comment: Also posted on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48568/755) and [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14751).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: I just deleted the redundancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [FOMA](https://code.google.com/p/foma/) which is a C library (It is also available as standalone executable for Windows). It is based on [Kimmo Koskenniemi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimmo_Koskenniemi)'s computational model that utilizes finite-state transducers. It is the open source version of [xfst](http://www.fsmbook.com/). You can see a quick crash course [here](https://code.google.com/p/foma/wiki/GettingStarted).

It is very easy to use foma. [This repo](https://github.com/yurap/spanish-morphology) on github could serve as a sample (Check out the `spanish.lexc` and `spanish.foma` files). If you fire up foma and put the two scripts in the same directory, you can load the file and test the morphological realizer:

foma[0]: source spanish.foma
Opening file 'spanish.foma'.
defined Word: 1.6 kB. 2 states, 64 arcs, Cyclic.
defined Cleanup: 276 bytes. 1 state, 2 arcs, Cyclic.
Root...5, A...2, N...2, V1...65, V2...65, V3...65
Building lexicon...
Determinizing...
Minimizing...
Done!
7.9 kB. 289 states, 441 arcs, 199 paths.
defined Lexicon: 7.9 kB. 289 states, 441 arcs, 199 paths. 
9.2 kB. 290 states, 505 arcs, Cyclic.

Now the good thing about FOMA is that it is two-ways. It can realize and analyze morphological forms at the same time. If you apply *up* it dissects forms, but if you apply *down* it acts as a realizer:

```
foma[1]: up                       
apply up> leo                     
leo+N+Sg                          
leo+A+Sg                          
leir+V+3C+PresenteIndicativo+1P+Sg
leer+V+2C+PresenteIndicativo+1P+Sg
lear+V+1C+PresenteIndicativo+1P+Sg
```

In the case of to-be, here's an example of how to use the transducer as a realizer:

```
foma[1]: down
apply down> estar+V+1C+PresenteIndicativo+3P+Sg
esta
```

Remember that you define the tags yourself at the start of the lexc script, so you can easily change or augment the existing script in that repo. If you actually read through the documentation, you'll quickly get the hang of it. It's very convenient and easy to use. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to do everything you suggested but till now I can't integrate it into my Java Project do you have any idea. I was trying the following command "cat mytext.txt | flookup -x -i spanish.foma" where mytext.txt contains "estar+V+1C+PresenteIndicativo+3P+Sg" and the flag -i should perform the down operation

Comment: Dear Ahmed, I am afraid I don't know how you should incorporate it into Java, because I am not a Java programmer. In Python and on Windows however, I would do something like `subprocess.check_output('type mytext.txt | flookup -x -i spanish.foma', shell=True)`. There must be some similar procedure available in Java. You've got to find an os module that would let you execute the program in shell and send back the result to your Java program.